# How to disable column header sorting in a jtable after RowFilter filtering is applied

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, rowfilter

I have a `JTable` which is passed to another class when a `JToggleButton` is clicked, a popup with parameters for filtering appears and the `JTable` is filtered using `RowFilter` with the given parameters. When I display the filtering is happening as expected. But when I click on a column header sorting the rows get sorted based on the original `JTable` values, not only with the filtered ones.

[image: The Image describing the issue.]

How to disable such sorting? Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to override the `isSortable(int)` method of `TableRowSorter` to prevent that column from being sorted:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class DisableSortingTest {
  private static String[] columnNames = {"ID", "NAME", "SALARY"};
  private static Object[][] data = {
    {1, "abcd", 2000},
    {2, "xyz",  1800},
    {3, "ijkl", 4600},
    {4, "pqrs", 3400},
    {5, "efgh", 5000}
  };
  private final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
    @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
      return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
    }
  };
  private final JCheckBox checkBox = new JCheckBox("filter");
  private final RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>() {
    @Override public boolean include(Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
      return "pqrs".equals(entry.getModel().getValueAt(entry.getIdentifier(), 1));
    }
  };
  private final JTable table = new JTable(model);
  private final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model) {
    @Override public boolean isSortable(int column) {
      return getRowFilter() == null;
    }
  };
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    table.setRowSorter(sorter);
    checkBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JCheckBox c = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
        sorter.setRowFilter(c.isSelected() ? filter : null);
        sorter.setSortKeys(null);
      }
    });
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(checkBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new DisableSortingTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting and filtering works fine for me without doing anything special.

I suggest you start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting).

So download the demo code and play with it. Make this code your starting code and then customize this code with your actual table data.